# Regex to match url in log file is giving line continuation error - what do I need to escape?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to analyze a reverse access log and have a regex to match the base url, put it in a variable and then print the variable. It says that print is illegal syntax. I've played around with all kinds of escaping the regex all causing various other errors to pop up. What am I missing?

```
import re, sys, glob, os

with open('log.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
       match = re.search("http|https):\/\/(.*?)./"
        print("match")
```

Comment: You have an unmatched `)` and the `re.search` method is not complete. Use `match = re.search(r"https?://([^/]*)", line)`

Comment: Trying to edit your question to block-quote the code (to improve legibility), it looks like your indentation is not uniform, and that's a syntax error in Python.

Comment: Well your call to `re.search` is wrong, because it is missing the second parameter, which should be a string containing a URL.

Comment: Wiktor Stribizew - your suggestion nailed it. If you want to put it as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @kmkelmor I [posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56482290/3832970).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unmatched `)` in the `http|https):\/\/(.*?)./` pattern and the `re.search` method is not complete.

Use

```
match = re.search(r"https?://([^/]*)", line)
```

**Pattern details**

- `http` - a `http` string
- `s?` - an optional `s`
- `://` - a `://` substring
- `([^/]*)` - Capturing group 1: any 0 or more chars other than `/`

If you plan to print the matched value instead of the whole line access the right `.group()`:

```
import re, sys, glob, os

with open('log.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = re.search(r"https?://([^/]*)", line)
        if match:                 # Always check if there is a match before accessing groups
            print(match.group(1)) # Only print capture group value, group() will print the whole match
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your original expression, I'm guessing that here we wish to find some URLs with an slash at the end, for which we would be starting with this simple expression:

```
https?:\/\/(.+?)\/
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/siGKa1/1/)

if the end slash might not be desired, we would simplify it to:

```
https?:\/\/[^\s]+
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9IWjcC/1/)

or we can continue add/remove our boundaries, if we like so.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"https?:\/\/[^\s]+"

test_str = ("https://somedomain/\n"
    "https://somedomain")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Comment: I like the fact that your answer sets up some iteration - but I couldn't figure out how to make it work through a file line by line as the string without having each match be Match1